# Не получается принять в контроллере значение

Tags: api, asp.net-core, postman

Не пойму почему в контроллере `productId` приходит 0. Вот контроллер:

```
    [Route("Test/Post")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostTest(IFormFile files, int productId)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string path = null;
            if (files != null)
            {
                path = "/ProductImages/" + files.FileName;
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_env.WebRootPath + path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await files.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
                return Ok(productId);
            }
            else return BadRequest("Model is not valid");
        }
        else return BadRequest("Model is not valid");
    }
```

Пробую:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, проверять `files` на `null` *после* обращения к `files.FileName` - несколько поздно.

Comment: @Igor это значит что в `files` приходит null, почему?